# joint.js trigger drag start on a new cloned element

Tags: jquery, jointjs

How can I trigger pointerdown/dragstart on a cloned joint element in joint js?
`toolBoxPointerDown` is triggered when `pointerdown` event is fired on toolbox paper.
`addNode` is triggered when `pointerup` event is fired on `_this.paperDrag`.

```
var toolBoxPointerDown = function(cell, event) {
        _this.action = 'addNode';
        $(document.body).append(_this.paperDrag.$el); 
        _this.clone = cell.model.clone(), _this.cloneBbox = cell.getBBox();

        _this.clone.set("position", {
            x: cell.model.attributes.position.x,
            y: cell.model.attributes.position.y 
        }), _this.paperDrag.addCell(_this.clone), _this.paperDrag.setDimensions("100%", "100%");

        _this.paperDrag.$el.offset({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });

        _this.paperDrag.findViewByModel(_this.clone.id).pointerdown();
    }

    var addNode = function(node, position) {
        var celltoAdd = _this.clone.clone();
        celltoAdd.set('position', { x: _this.clone.get('position').x - $('.toolbox').width(), y: _this.clone.get('position').y });


        if(celltoAdd.attributes.position.x > - 50){
            renderNode(celltoAdd.attributes);
        }
         _this.paperDrag.$el.detach();
        _this.clone.remove();
        _this.action = 'nodeAdded';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code to your paper builder:

```
_this.paperDrag.on('element:pointerup', this.addNode , this);
_this.paperDrag.on('element:pointerdown', this.toolBoxPointerDown , this);
```

---

Some explanations: the `joint.dia.ElementView` has built in pointerdown and pointerup, the last code line of these two functions make notify like this:

`this.notify('element:pointerdown', evt, x, y);`

and your `paper.on('element:pointerdown')` is been executed after that notification has accrued.